# Inconsistent Result for Web3 Constant Method Call

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, contract-development, constant

Deployed a local private Ethereum environment. While trying to invoke a constant method of a solidity contract getting inconsistent results.

Sometimes the result is returned and mostly not.

When I tried to fetch the data from geth command line was able to successfully list down the results every time.

In the Nodejs code below created a loop of 20 iterations to fetch the asset price. Sometimes 10-15 times the result is returned correctly and many a times in none of the iterations result is found rather it says 0.

> **Contract**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.9;

contract Asset {

    address public owner;
    struct Asset {
        string title;
        string description;
        uint  assetTime;
        uint price;
    }

    Asset[] public  assets;

    event LogAssetAdded(address indexed fromAddress, string description);

    // add asset
    function addAsset(string  description1, string title1, uint price1,uint assetTime1) 
      returns (uint, string, string, uint, uint) {
        uint assetID = assets.length++;
        Asset o = assets[assetID];

        o.description = description1;
        o.assetTime=assetTime1;
        o.title = title1;
        o.price = price1;

        LogAssetAdded(msg.sender, description1);

        return (assetID, assets[assetID].description, assets[assetID].title, assets[assetID].price, 
          assets[assetID].assetTime);
    }

    //return the  number of assets 
    function assetCount() public constant returns(uint) {
        uint assetCount =assets.length;
        return(assetCount);
    }

    function getAssetPrice(uint assetID) public constant returns(uint) {
        return assets[assetID].price;
    }

    function getDefAssetPrice() public constant returns(uint) {
        return assets[assets.length-1].price;
    }

    function getDefAssetTitle() public constant returns(string) {
        return assets[assets.length-1].title;
    }

    function getDefAssetTime() public constant returns(uint) {
        return assets[assets.length-1].assetTime;
    }
}
```

> **NodeJs Client Code**

```
const rpcURL = 'http://localhost:9081'
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:9081"));

const fs = require("fs");

let abi ='<<Apply ABI>>';

let bytecode = '<<Apply Bytecode >>'
let gasEstimate = web3.eth.estimateGas({data: bytecode});

let assetContract = web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(abi));
const account = '<<Provide from account>>';

var contractAddress = '<<Provide Contract Address>>';

var ctr1 = 0;
var contract = assetContract.at(contractAddress);

// Method to create asset
function addAsset(){
    contract.addAsset.sendTransaction("Asset Description", " Asset Title", 41202, 41203, {from: account, gas: 400000} 
    , function(err, result){
        if(err){
            console.log('Error '+ err);    
        }
        else{
            console.log('Transaction Hash: '+ result);
            getAssetPrice();
        }
    });
}

// Method to fetch asset price
function getAssetPrice(){  
    for(var i=0;i<20;i++){
      contract.getAssetPrice(0, (error, result) => {
        if (!error && result>0) {
            ctr1++;
            console.log(ctr1 +": getAssetPrice: "+ result);
        }
        if (!error){
             console.log("Error occurred: "+ error);
        }
    });
}

addAsset();
//getAssetPrice()
```

> **Dependencies**

```
"web3": "^0.19",
"solc": "^0.4.9"
```

> **Geth Version**

```
 v1.9.0 windows-amd64, go1.10.3
```

> **Geth Instance Command**

```
geth --mine --minerthreads=1 --datadir D:/Ethereum/env-II/data/node1 --networkid 4224 --nodiscover --rpc --rpcport "9081" --port "30301" --rpccorsdomain "*" --nat "any" --rpcapi eth,web3,personal,net,miner --unlock 0 --password "D:/Ethereum/env-II/pwd.txt"  --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --verbosity 2 console
```

> **Geth command line result**

```
> var assetContractRef = eth.contract('<<Contract abi>>');
> var assetContract = assetContractRef.at('<<Contract address>>')
> assetContract.getAssetPrice(1);
> 41202
```

> **Result on invoking with Call**

```
Option 1: contract.getAssetPrice(0).call((error, result) => {                            

TypeError: contract.getCallPrice(...).call is not a function

Option 2: contract.getAssetPrice.call(0, (error, result) => {

Faced same result i.e. inconsistent output.
```

> **Note**

I have tried this implementation, with Web3 1.0.0-beta.52 as well with a bit modified nodejs code i.e. specific to the web3 1.0.0 signatures, but have faced the same inconsistent results. If required could share that version of Nodejs code as well.

Comment: Are you sure that the ```addAsset()``` transaction is being mined before you call ```getAssetPrice()```? You'll get ```0``` until it has.

Comment: Well I am checking getAssetPrice() by directly invoking it, once the addAsset() method is invoked earlier, specifically to avoid any such sort of confusion :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35186)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `.call()` when invoking constant (view) methods. Check out this page of the Web3js docs to get familiar: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call

At a glance, I think all you would have to change is this line:

```
contract.getAssetPrice(0, (error, result) => {
```

To this:

```
contract.getAssetPrice(0).call((error, result) => {
```

Comment: Thomas, thanks for your reply. I have already tried the same and here is the error detail.      contract.getAssetPrice(0).call((error, result) => {                            ^

TypeError: contract.getCallPrice(...).call is not a function

Comment: This type of call is supported by web3 version 1.0 on-wards. If you check above the one i am using is web3 0.19.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a request many times within a certain period of time. 
Your result might be due to the TCP connection. You are using `http` , try using `websocket`  as a [provider](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/getting-started.html#adding-web3-js).

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("http://localhost:9081"));
```

Comment: When i call it single time (i.e. without a loop) then it should always return the required result which anyway is not happening.

Comment: This may happen due to the TCP issue. Try once using WebSocket. And please share the result.

Comment: It will be helpful if you could share the link or details about this TCP issue you mentioned above to have a better understanding.